Are there deepfake detection technologies available outside of the major companies?
I've been reading a lot about deepfakes lately and it's got me wondering about how we can detect them. I know big tech companies like Google and Facebook are working on this, but what about the rest of us?
I'm curious if there are any tools or technologies out there for spotting deepfakes that don't require a Silicon Valley budget. Maybe some open-source stuff, or solutions from universities or smaller companies?
I'd love to hear about:
Any cool projects or tools you've come across
How well they actually work compared to the big tech solutions
What it takes to get them up and running
I'm not super technical, so if you could explain things in simple terms, that'd be great. Just trying to understand what options are out there for the average person or smaller organization concerned about deepfakes.
Thanks in advance for any insights!
